# Why delete command is not executing from c#?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-delete

Please check the following code:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string y = foredidel.Text;
        try
        {
            using (var sc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
            {
                sc.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM fixap WHERE Id = @word";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", y);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
    }
```

When the button is clicked, the specified row should be deleted, but it's not doing anything!
Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing correct Id? Turn on SQL profiler and check the log

Comment: @DanielA.White Its just a practice project, no worries! ;)

Comment: Have you try a simple debug like: Build your query in a string, display it for simple inspection, past it to a SQL client to see it run?

Comment: If it's a practice project then there is no reason to use SqlComand with SQL injection vulnerability. This is not old legacy code with limited support and no nugget allowed. please try any Orm. and make safe code easier.

Comment: If you run same script from sql manager, will that delete your row? Also check if connection is the same.

Comment: @xdtTransform Its a simple code, it should work at once! :)

Comment: @SeM Yeah! It works their, but not from c#!

Comment: @Yash May be there are some restrictions on sql user? But in that case you will most probably get an error.

Comment: @SeM How would I overcome it?

Comment: Check your connection string, is this pointing to the expected server, instance, and database? Check the incoming value in variable `y`, is this the expected value? Check the result of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` which returns the number of rows affected, what is the value? I recommend you step through the code with break points and inspect the values as you execute the code.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied, I have my answer below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was working along with some javascript, so it was like....

1. `onclick` give id's value to innerHtml of `<asp:Label>`.
2. Then take that value to the variable `y` in **C#**(you can check my question for
   that variable).
3. Now as it was `runat='server'`, so I used it to concatenate with my
   SqlCommand`("@word", y)`.

I don't know if it was a problem of `<asp:Label>`, but when I changed it to `<asp:TextBox>` it worked successfully!

---

So, answer is just to change `<asp:Label>` to `<asp:TextBox>` and according to 1st point change `innerHTML` to `value`, and it worked!